# Finding common set of values between dictionaries in the correct combination

Tags: python, dictionary, combinations, python-itertools

I am trying to build an Inference system in **Python** which will say if a Query can be inferred or not based on the existing statements in my Knowledge Base.

The input is:

> 1. Predicate1(x,y) ^ Predicate2(x,y,z) ^ Predicate3(y,z) ^ Predicate4(Constant,z) => Predicate5(r)
> 2. Predicate1(X1,Y1)
> 3. Predicate1(X1,Y2)
> 4. Predicate1(X4,Y5)
> 5. Predicate2(X1,Y1,Z1)
> 6. Predicate2(X4,Y2,Z1)
> 7. Predicate3(Y2,X1)
> 8. Predicate3(Y1,Z1)
> 9. Predicate4(Constant1,Z1)
> 10. Predicate4(Constant2,Z5)

and my Query is Predicate5(R1).

So the LHS of 1. has to be true for my Query to be true.

All the arguments for Predicates are either variables(lower case) or constants(starts in upper case) or a mix of both constants and variables and there can be arbitrary number of arguments.

I am using a Recursive Backward Chaining approach to compute all possible values for each predicate -- each for Predicate1, Predicate2 etc, which returns a **list of dictionaries**.

For example, each conjunct on the LHS,

Predicate1 will have `[{'x':'X1','y':'Y1'},{'x':'X1','y':'Y2'},{'x':'X4','y':'Y5'}]`

Predicate2 will have `[{'x':'X1','y':'Y1','z':'Z1'},{'x':'X4','y':'Y2','z':'Z1'}]`

Predicate3 will have `[{'y':'Y2','z':'X1'},{'y':'Y1','z':'Z1'}]`

Predicate4 will have `[{'z':'Z1'},{'z':'Z5}]`

The approach that I have in mind is creating a new variable-to-list of values mapping(another dictionary) by scanning all the dictionaries for each Predicate and eliminating the values for a variable that are not present in the other Predicates' dictionaries, and adding new variables to this dictionary if they were not already present.

The problem here is it has to be exactly in the **correct combination**. For example, Predicate2's `{'x':'X4','y':'Y2','z':'Z1'}` can't be true because of Predicate1's dictionary(there's no 'x':'X4' **and** 'y':'Y2' for Predicate1).

I would essentially need to compute the common variable-to-value(s) that are True across all the Predicates and return them. If one/more such combinations doesn't exist, return False;otherwise return the list and True.

For the above example 'x' should take only 'X1', 'y' only 'Y1', 'z':'Z1'.
i.e., **the output should be [{x:'X1','y':'Y1','z':'Z1'}]**

Should I use itertools or a similar approach to do this? Any thoughts on how to go about doing this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Please give a full example of input and output

Comment: ```z:Z1``` does not exist in ```Predicate1``` - why is ```z:Z1``` an acceptable outcome?

Comment: @wwii Because for `Predicate1` - variable `z` itself doesn't exist in its argument list. `Predicate1(x,y)` reads "Predicate1 will be True if there exists some values for `x` and `y` -- its arguments". (other variables like `z`,`r` and its corresponding values do not matter for `Predicate1`, since they do not exist in the argument list of `Predicate1`). Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Is the argument list constant for each predicate or variable?

Comment: @wwii, can be both. In a clause -- 1. in the input the arguments can take a mix of both constant and variable. For facts, 2. - 10., the arguments will only take constants.

Comment: Sounds like you want to count the number of predicates each argument(key) *appears* in; turn the dictionaries into tuples (items) and count them, any unique tuple that has a count equal to the first accumulation(?) is the result.   ```collections.Counter``` and using ```operator.itemgetter``` to filter might help with this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to solve your problem. It will guarantee that your dict always comes in the same order.